# Why can we turn this into a function like that?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

To find volume bounded by $z=x^2+y^2$ and $z=y$. We can rewrite this as 
$$y=x^2+y^2$$
$$0=y-x^2-y^2$$
And then we can say this is a function $f(x,y)=y-x^2-y^2$ and take a double integral of it.

But why can we rewrite it like this and make it a function? I know this may seem like I should know it already, but I don't think this was ever explained to me. I'm used to having some variable equal to some function of variable(s). And I solved other volume problems by integrating $z=f(x,y)$, having found the boundaries with the help of other given equations. Although in this case it didn't work, for some reason, I found the boundaries correct but integrating $z=f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ gave a wrong result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of this in analogy with how you compute the area between two curves.  If you have two functions $y=g(x)$ and $y=h(x)$ and you want to know the area they bound, you need to integrate the function $f(x)=g(x)-h(x)$.  To find the limits of integration, you have to find where the two curves cross, so you set $g(x)=h(x)$ (or, equivalently, $f(x)=0$) and solve.

This is the same thing, with an extra variable.  To find the volume between two surfaces $z=g(x,y)$ and $z=h(x,y)$, you need to integrate the function $f(x,y)=g(x,y)-h(x,y)$.  To find the boundary curve of the region of integration, you need to find where the two surfaces cross, so you set $g(x,y)=h(x,y)$, or equivalently $f(x,y)=0$.

Comment: Thanks. I think it makes sense. Although a big confusion for me is why it couldn't be solved the way it worked with all the other problems. For instance volume bounded by $z=x^2+y^2$ and $z=4$, or by $4x^2+y^2=4z$ and $z=2$. This one was the only one where I got the wrong result, solving by integrating $z=f(x,y)$.

Comment: Without knowing how you solved those other problems I can't really comment on how this is different, but I would say that those problems should be solved using *exactly* this same approach.

Comment: Well, for instance this problem is almost identical to the one in question: $z=x^2+y^2$ and $z=4$. It can be solved like you said it, or like I did it originally: $4=x^2+y^2$, so $x=\pm\sqrt{4-y^2}$; from which we know that $-\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq x \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $-2 \leq y \leq 2$, and then integrate $z=f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. In fact, integrating either of these $x^2+y^2$, $4-(x^2+y^2)$, $x^2+y^2-4$ gives the absolute value of the correct result. Maybe that's some sort of weird coincidence, and only works since the other $z$ is a constant, but generally not a correct way to solve this.

Comment: If you integrate $z=f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ you are measuring the volume *below* the surface $z=x^2+y^2$ and above the circle $x^2+y^2=4$ in the plane.  If you integrate $z=4-(x^2+y^2)$ you are measuring the volume *above* the surface and below the plane $z=4$. The fact that these happen to be equal to each other is, in fact, just a coincidence.

Comment: Right. Thanks again.